# I want to display something from a different DB table in a HTML Table

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I would like to show content from someone that takes a course. 
What I am displaying right now is the Name and email of the course member.
With that I want to display the course from a different DB table in the database.
in the table `cursist` I have the following:
id INT(4)
naam VARCHAR(255)
EMAIL VARCHAR(255)
As for the `cursus` table I have the following:
cid INT(4)
cursus VARCHAR(255)

I have this code right now

```
        <?php 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cursist";
    $res = $db->query($sql);

    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
      while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" .$row["cursus"]. "</td><td>" . "<a href=\"editcursus.php?cid=$row[cid]\">Wijzig</a>" . "</td></tr>";
        } 
      } else {
        echo "0 Resultaten gevonden";
      }
    $db->close();
    ?>
```

I have tried using ``Inner Join` which did not work when I tried it, I would love if someone could help me with this problem.

> The question is, How do I make it so the course from a different DB
>   table shows in the SAME HTML Form on my webpage.

Kind regards,
Mark.

Comment: does the user have any relationship with the courses, i.e  are you trying to display courses the user has probably subscribed for or something

Comment: There is no link between the two tables. i.e. `cursist` doesn't have any `cursus` assigned to them. This makes it impossible to get a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at SQL Joins which might help you here.

Regarding your main question, the SQL Query should work. 
A select * and inner join won't work in most cases as you have to specify the fields you need from the database:

```
SELECT CURSIST.id,
      CURSIST.naam,
      CURSIST.email,
      CURSUS.cursus
FROM CURSIST 
INNER JOIN CURSUS 
     ON CURSIST.id=CURSUS.cid;
```

I don't see the whole question/needed things but I thing your database layout might have a missing table.

If I see this correct you have two following Tables:

```
CURSIST(id,naam,email)
CURSUS(id,cursus)
```

It might be that one cursist can have multiple curses and one cursus has multiple cursists.
So you should have a table between cursist and cursus. If you create a table for this you can solve the N:M solution between those two.     `DEELNEMERS(cursist_id,cursus_id)`

Then the query would be:

```
SELECT CURSIST.id,
       CURSIST.naam,
       CURSIST.email,
       CURSUS.cursus
 FROM CURSIST 
 INNER JOIN DEELNEMERS
      ON CURSIST.id=DEELNEMERS.cursist_id;
 INNER JOIN CURSUS
      ON DEELNEMERS.cursus_id=CURSUS.id;
```

Helpful links regarding joins:

1. [W3Schools SQL Joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)
2. [3rd Normal form SQL](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-11-database-third-normal-form-explained-in-simple-english/)

@Update: @Mark_Ed i once commented your code, hope this helps

Edited approach:

```php
<?php 
   $sql = "SELECT CURSIST.id,
                  CURSIST.naam,
                  CURSIST.email,
                  CURSUS.cursus,
                  CURSUS.cid
           FROM CURSIST 
           INNER JOIN CURSUS 
           ON CURSIST.id=CURSUS.cid;";

   $res = $db->query($sql);
   // $res contains the result of the sql-query at this point.
   if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
     // if the rows got returned from sql, this block is executes.

     while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
     // while the $row contains something this block is exectued.
     /** the Object $row[] contains the "fields" from the sql query.
     /   for example a $row["naam"] would return the name from the cursist
     /   here you take the name of the cursus. 
     **/
            echo "<tr><td>Cursus: " .$row["cursus"]. "</td><td>Cursist Naam: " .$row["naam"]. "</td><td>" . "<a             
                 href=\"editcursus.php?cid=$row[cid]\">Wijzig</a>" . "</td> 
                 </tr>";
     } 
   } else {
      echo "0 Resultaten gevonden";
   }
   $db->close();
  ?>
```

Comment: Hey! how would I print the 'cursus' on the screen with this query? Still kind of new to PHP

Comment: When I used the code above, it displays "0 Resultaten gevonden" aka 0 Results found. Can't really find what's wrong also..

Comment: Does the SQL Query deliver results back? The query delivers every entry where the Cursist.id is in the cursus table as cid. if the user has no cursus assigned that might be the reason why no results are coming back from the database.

Comment: when I change the Cursus id to one of the users id it does show up.